# Is it possible to compare two versions of remote for the same repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

This question is related to Git, SourceTree and Bitbucket.

A branch was deleted accidently from a remote on bitbucket and it was not discovered until many months later. The name and commit numbers are unknown but it is clear that some information was deleted and it should exist in one branch, could be more.

There is one old version of the repository on a computer which has not been updated with fetch for quite sometime so it is very much out of date with the remote. There is a small chance that it contains the branch that was deleted on remote. How can I compare this old repository copy with the remote to see what commits exist in one but not the other? I can't compare branches since the branch in remote was deleted accidently. Maybe there is a way to test if branch exists in one but not the other?

Comment: Try fetching all `git fetch --all` and then listing the remote branches `git branch -r`?

Comment: @evolutionbox : I think the OP wants to avoid to accidentally drop the existing `origin/xxx` branches on that specific clone

Comment: @LeGEC ah cool. If that’s the case, maybe they could clone the different remotes again elsewhere? Then list the remote branches?

Answer (score 1):

On "that clone which still has the old version", you can make sure to keep pointers to the remote branches :

- you can list the remote branches known to that clone using either `git branch -r`, or `git for-each-ref` (that command has a more predictable output when you use it in scripts) :

```
# this will list all the existing 'remote branches' from origin known to a local repo :
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin

# you can drop the leading 'refs/remotes/origin' from each line :
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin
```

- from the output of the above command, you can create branches or tags pointing to their current state :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin |\
   while read br; do
      # create a branch named 'backup/foo' pointing to 'origin/foo' :
      git branch backup/$br origin/$br
   done
```

You can now update the remote branches (`git fetch`), and compare `origin/*` with `backup/*`